# EF Code First table.add() Method always returning nullreference Exception on table is null

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am new to Entity framework code first.. Whats wrong with the following  code..

```
Sub Main()
        Dim _Context As New Sample()
        _Context.Database.Initialize(True)
        Dim dbHead
        dbHead = New MainDb("Hai", "Bye")
        _Context.MainTable.Add(dbHead)
        _Context.SaveChanges()


End Sub
```

My Db Context is named as sample is given below

```
Public Class Sample
    Inherits DbContext

    Public MainTable As DbSet(Of MainDb)

    Public Sub New()

    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnModelCreating(modelBuilder As DbModelBuilder)
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(New MyDbContextIntializer())
        MyBase.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder)
    End Sub

    Public Class MyDbContextIntializer
        Inherits DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges(Of Sample)

        Protected Overrides Sub Seed(context As Sample)
            MyBase.Seed(context)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Class
```

This is the main Indent Class

```
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema
Imports System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

<Table("MainDb")>
Public Class MainDb

    Private _Name As String
    <Key()>
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _Name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Name = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _Class As String
    Public Property ClassName() As String
        Get
            Return _Class
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            _Class = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal CN As String)
        ClassName = CN
        Me.Name = Name
    End Sub

End Class
```

The Main table is always null.. table not creating up.... Null Reference exception is shown. Please help me in regards with this..

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you're defining `MainTable` as a field, but the `DbContext` class works its magic by looking for properties.  Try changing it to:

```
Public Property MainTable As DbSet(Of MainDb)
```

(An auto-implemented property like that is good enough -- you don't need to initialize it yourself, the class will do it for you.)

Hopefully that will do the trick!